# Latency requirement inside the kubernetes cluster across WAN link

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have a k8s cluster with master in data center but minions are at remote sites through WAN links. Is there any latency requirement to ensure the cluster will function across the WAN?

Answer (score 0):

About to start testing this (in anger).

My .50c advice would be to make sure etcd is tuned correctly for the level of latency you will have and the level of latency you might have if one site goes down.

https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/tuning.html